# Parse intersecting name ranges with POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I have problems to parse formulas which contain intersecting name ranges with apache-poi.
For example if I try to parse a formula like "=SUM((Total_Cost!Jan):(Total_Cost!Apr_))" where Total_Cost, Jan and Apr_ are name ranges which overlap i receive the following exception:

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Parse error near char 16 'J' in specified formula 'SUM((Total_Cost Jan):(Total_Cost Apr_))'. Expected ')' 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.expected(FormulaParser.java:219) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Match(FormulaParser.java:251) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:1108) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1079) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1066) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(FormulaParser.java:1426) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.additiveExpression(FormulaParser.java:1526) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.concatExpression(FormulaParser.java:1510) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.comparisonExpression(FormulaParser.java:1467) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Arguments(FormulaParser.java:1051) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.function(FormulaParser.java:936) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseNonRange(FormulaParser.java:558) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeable(FormulaParser.java:429) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeExpression(FormulaParser.java:268) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:1119) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1079) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1066) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(FormulaParser.java:1426) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.additiveExpression(FormulaParser.java:1526) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.concatExpression(FormulaParser.java:1510) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.comparisonExpression(FormulaParser.java:1467) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.unionExpression(FormulaParser.java:1447) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:1568) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:176)

Has anyone experience with this kind of issue? Is the Parser just not able to parse such formulas or am I doing something wrong? I have no ideas left to fix that problem except writing my own parser which i want to avoid...

Comment: Is there a reason why you've put the named range names in extra brackets?

Comment: you mean "=SUM((Total_Cost!Jan):(Total_Cost!Apr_))" ? 
No should just illustrate whats written in the cell. The brackets are not part of the cells content.

Comment: oh, sry. I have misunderstood your question. Yes there is a reason. Without the brackets it calculates the wrong result.